# print an enumerated list in multiple columns

Tags: python, multiple-columns, enumerate

I want to print an enumerated list in user specified columns.

```
import random

lst = random.sample(range(100), 30)
counter = 0

for pos, num in enumerate(sorted(lst)):
    if counter % 2 == 0:
        print '(%s) %s' %(pos, num),
        counter = counter + 1
    else:
        print '(%s) %s'.rjust(16) %(pos, num)
        counter = counter + 1
```

This gives:

```
(0) 3          (1) 6
(2) 7          (3) 10
(4) 11          (5) 13
(6) 17          (7) 18
(8) 20          (9) 25
(10) 45          (11) 46
(12) 48          (13) 51
(14) 58          (15) 59
(16) 60          (17) 63
(18) 68          (19) 69
(20) 77          (21) 81
(22) 83          (23) 84
(24) 87          (25) 89
(26) 93          (27) 94
(28) 97          (29) 98
```

How do I print a list where first 15 numbers are in the first column and second fifteen are in the second? I've seen some examples where `range(start, stop, step)` have been used to create sub-lists and resultant rows have been printed but I would have to lose enumeration and just print the numbers.

Comment: You should add a tag for the language you're using to help people find your question. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "user specified" part of your question is tricky. How does the user specify what they want in each column? Can they specify more than two columns? etc.

However, if you know you have 30 items, and you know that you want the 1st 15 in the first column and the next 15 in the 2nd column I believe the following will do the trick:

```
for i in xrange(15):
    first = '(%s) %s' % (i, lst[i])
    padding = ' ' * (30 - len(first))
    second = '(%s) %s' % (i + 15, lst[i + 15])
    print '%s%s%s' % (first, padding, second)
```

Comment: `(0) 60
         \n(15) 23
(1) 86
         \n(16) 84`
The numbers infront of 1st column are on different lines!

Comment: Ooops. I think changing the 1st to `system.out.write()` and leaving the 2nd as-is will fix things.

Comment: and can the second column's symmetry be maintained? i.e all the numbers start on the same position in the stack

Comment: @koogee The for loop sets `i` to successive values, 0, 1, 2, etc. the first line in the for loop writes the value of i and the value of the i^th item is lst. `print` automatically adds a carriage return character so we use `system.out.write` instead. The 2nd line in the loop writes out the value of `i + 15` and the (i + 15)^th item in lst. Thus, for the first line we write out elements 0 and 0 + 15 = 0. The second time through we write out elements 1 and 1 +15 = 16, etc.  I'm not sure what you mean about maintaining symmetry. Can you clarify.

Comment: @koogee If this answer seems good, please mark it as correct.

Comment: by symmentry, I meant the second columns entry don't start on the same position as they being justified according to the entry in the first column to their left. since the entries vary in length, the second column looks and prints uneven.

Comment: @koogee I updated the code to make the columns even. Now I create `first`, the string in the first column, `padding`, a string of spaces that brings us to column 30 (30 chosen arbitrarily, and `second`, the string for the second column. the print line then concatenates these 3 pieces into a single line. Please note that this is pretty bad coding style and is written this way just for illustration purposes.

Comment: its pretty simple compared to the convoluted way i was trying to hammer enumerate into printing columns :)

Answer (score 2):

```
def print_table(seq, columns=2):
    table = ''
    col_height = len(seq) / columns
    for x in xrange(col_height):
        for col in xrange(columns):
            pos = (x * columns) + col
            num = seq[x + (col_height * col)]
            table += ('(%s) %s' % (pos, num)).ljust(16)
        table += '\n'
    print table
```

Results

```
>>> print_table(lst)
(0) 0           (1) 59          
(2) 3           (3) 61          
(4) 5           (5) 65          
(6) 7           (7) 75          
(8) 8           (9) 79          
(10) 17         (11) 81         
(12) 18         (13) 83         
(14) 22         (15) 84         
(16) 24         (17) 86         
(18) 43         (19) 88         
(20) 48         (21) 89         
(22) 49         (23) 92         
(24) 51         (25) 96         
(26) 52         (27) 97         
(28) 58         (29) 99         

>>> print_table(lst, 3)
(0) 0           (1) 48          (2) 81          
(3) 3           (4) 49          (5) 83          
(6) 5           (7) 51          (8) 84          
(9) 7           (10) 52         (11) 86         
(12) 8          (13) 58         (14) 88         
(15) 17         (16) 59         (17) 89         
(18) 18         (19) 61         (20) 92         
(21) 22         (22) 65         (23) 96         
(24) 24         (25) 75         (26) 97         
(27) 43         (28) 79         (29) 99         

>>>
```

Still thinking of a way to specify between horizontal or verticle numbering.

Also, if the number of items in `seq` is not divisible by `columns` then the remainder won't get printed.

---edit---

Misunderstood the OP. There, just like Olivers.

```
def print_table(lst):
    table = ''
    half = len(lst) / 2
    for x1 in xrange(half):
        x2 = x1 + half
        col1 = '(%s) %s' % (x1, lst[x1])
        col2 = '(%s) %s\n' % (x2, lst[x2])
        table += col1.ljust(16) + col2
    print table
```

Comment: the list must be enumerated with numbers ascending vertically, not horizontally

Comment: Do you mean you want to number the items in _descending_ order vertically?

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> lst
[87, 53, 82, 2, 76, 92, 98, 88, 74, 33, 15, 11, 58, 23, 10,
 65, 19, 83, 66, 38, 31, 21, 45, 85, 27, 84, 99, 55, 5, 26]
>>> hlen = len(lst)/2
>>> for i, t in enumerate(zip(lst, lst[hlen:])):
        print '({0:>2}) {2:>3}    ({1}) {3:>3}'.format(i, i+hlen, *t)

( 0)  87    (15)  65
( 1)  53    (16)  19
( 2)  82    (17)  83
( 3)   2    (18)  66
( 4)  76    (19)  38
( 5)  92    (20)  31
( 6)  98    (21)  21
( 7)  88    (22)  45
( 8)  74    (23)  85
( 9)  33    (24)  27
(10)  15    (25)  84
(11)  11    (26)  99
(12)  58    (27)  55
(13)  23    (28)   5
(14)  10    (29)  26
```

Comment: your use of dictionary is fascinating. as a beginner, im very curious how this works...hint?

Comment: Dict like structures are used for placing values inside a string with the .format() string method.  See more [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatexamples).